# find repeating dates between two datetime arrays python

Tags: python, arrays, datetime

I have two datetime arrays, and I am trying to output an array with only those dates which are repeated between both arrays.. I feel like this is something I should be able to answer myself, but I have spent a lot of time searching and I do not understand how to solve this.

```
>>> datetime1[0:4]
array([datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 19, 4, 0), 
datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 19, 5, 0),
datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 19, 6, 0),
datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 19, 7, 0)], dtype=object)

>>> datetime2[0:4]
array([datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 19, 3, 0),
datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 19, 4, 0),
datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 19, 5, 0),
datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 19, 6, 0)], dtype=object)
```

I've tried this below but I still do not understand why this does not work

```
>>> np.where(datetime1==datetime2)
(array([], dtype=int64),)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
datetime1==datetime2
```

Is an *element-wise comparison*.  It compares [0] with [0],  then [1] with [1], and gives you a boolean array.

Instead, try:

```
np.in1d(datetime1, datetime2)
```

This gives you a boolean array the same size as `datetime1`, set to True for those elements which exist in datetime2.

If your goal is only to get the *values* rather than the *indexes*, use this:

```
np.intersect1d(datetime1, datetime2)
```

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html

Answer (score 2):

I would say just iterate over the values of datetime1 and datetime2 and check for containment. So for example:

```
for date in datetime1:
    if date in datetime2:
        print(date)
```

Comment: For loops in NumPy are usually a poor solution.